# PYTHON Convert dates under 1900 (Negatives) to text date xlrd EXCEL

Tags: python, sql

Im getting an error trying to convert a date 1500-12-31 to tuple in python

if a date is under 1900 the Excel number is a negative one, i need to get a human readable text

Answer (score -1):

sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
a1 = sh.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=1) - 1

b=xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(a1,0)
print (b)

its done.